# I cannot understand what delegates are about

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I cannot understand what Delegates are used for in swift

I tried to search in any possible site what a delegate is and for what it is used for but I cannot completely grasp the meaning of them.

f.e. in this code

```
extension SignUpViewController : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    }
}
```

what are the delegates assigned to the ViewController supposed to do? and how can I understand how to use them?

Comment: If I were,I'd follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31934786/5175709). Get it to work. Then start breaking it, let it create errors and try to understand those errors. Why it breaks and how to fix them. Cuz that's exactly what I did 3 years ago. You'll learn a lot by doing this simple exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to think with an analogy:

There will be a "**speaker**" and a "**listener**".

`UIImagePickerController` is already configured to "**speak**" when events happen, so when something like `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` happens, it "**speaks**" .

In your scenario, the `UIViewController` should be the "**listener**", this is configured with:

`picker.delegate = self`, assuming `UIViewController` implements `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.

---

In other words, make the `UIViewController` the "**listener**" for when the `picker` "**speak**".

And everything that the picker "**speak**", will be "**listened**" via `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` by whoever is "**listening**".

---

**Note:** This is very superficial and abstract, of course it goes much beyond this, but I'm considering the OP situation.

Comment: Good example. To add onto this:  while it's configured to speak, its listener is unknown, the speaker never itself initializes the listener. It's merely a placeholder that gets assigner **later**. Nothing is listening until you do `picker.delegate = self`. It's like telling the speaker, here is your listener. Obviously the reason the listener isn't specified until then is because the listen can be _anything_. It could be a `UIViewController`, `SomeCustomizedClass`. 1/2

Comment: All that it needs to do is adopt **and** conform. Adopt is to do: `: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`. Conform is to include its function ie implement: `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
` 2/2

Answer (score 2):

A delgate is a connection between 2 data types commonly vcs , that enable 1 of them to send data to the other by calling a method from the protocol that the receiver is conforming to in you example you set

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.delegate = self  // connection here
```

above receiver is `SignUpViewController` instance and sender is `UIImagePickerController` instance after the user picks a photo/video the picker calls `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`  which is 1 of the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` methods , this what happens under the hood of

```
class UIImagePickerController { // look for it in framework visible part
   weak var delegate:UIImagePickerControllerDelegate?
   ....
   delegate?.imagePickerController(self,didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:info)
}
```