# Nothing happens when using a delegate

Tags: swift, delegates

I am trying to output text to viewDidLoad using a delegate (for test), however nothing happens

```
protocol LoaderDelegate: class {
  func LoadData(_ controller: SearchPhotosViewController)
}

class LoaderData: LoaderDelegate {
  func LoadData() {
    print("Hello from LoaderData")
  }
}

class SearchPhotosViewController: UICollectionViewController {

  // MARK: - Properties
  weak var delegate: LoaderDelegate?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Hello from viewDidLoad")
    delegate?.LoadData()
  }

}
```

Comment: Someone needs to create a strongly held instance of `LoaderData` and assign that to `delegate` in `SearchPhotosViewController`.  Right now, it is just `nil` and therefore does nothing.  This is usually done by the presenting VC.

Comment: delegate is nil. You need some class to explicitly handle the `delegate`, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719732/8869493

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should delete the parameter from `LoaderDelegate.LoadData`, because the current code does not compile (`LoaderData.LoadData`'s signature does not match that of the protocol).

```
protocol LoaderDelegate: class {
  func LoadData()
}
```

You have set up the delegate correctly, but you have not set the delegate a value. Usually, the delegate pattern is used to "pass data backward". In the view controller that presents `SearchPhotosViewController` (or whatever thing that is using `SearchPhotosViewController`), you set the `delegate` to an instance of `LoaderData`:

```
searchPhotosViewController.delegate = LoaderData()
```

And now when the search photos view is loaded, you will see "Hello from LoaderData" in the logs.

If `SearchPhotosViewController` is actually a root VC, then the delegate pattern is probably not suitable here. But you can still make it print "Hello from LoaderData" by setting `delegate` in `viewDidLoad` (but that's kind of pointless):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Hello from viewDidLoad")
    delegate = LoaderData()
    delegate?.LoadData()
}
```

Comment: I did not quite understand where I should add "searchPhotosViewController.delegate = LoaderData()"?

Comment: @CoffeeinTime What view controller presents `SearchPhotosViewController`? Put that line right before `SearchPhotosViewController` is presented.

Comment: I do not understand. How can I place this code somewhere other than the LoaderData class or the SearchPhotosViewController class, this will cause an error.

Comment: @CoffeeinTime do you only have those two classes in your project? If so, then you should not use the delegate pattern. Read my last paragraph.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how they work. In the future I want to use it to upload photos. Aren't delegates created for such purposes? To transfer part of the responsibilities to another class.

Comment: @CoffeeinTime unfortunately, no. As I said in my answer, delegates are used to pass data back to another object (usually the owner of `self`).

Comment: Maybe you can tell me ... I want to create a bootloader class that will upload photos to me and send them to the collection. (I'm trying to create an application in which the “tab bar controller” leads to several collections, the difference is only in the category of photos. And to avoid duplication of code, I was going to do it all in one place by creating a convenient class for loading.) How can I to implement a similar class that could change the collection I need and be able to upload photos?